# Reading from csv and plotting Date on x

Tags: csv, gnuplot, file-read

I am new to gnuplot and got stuck in plotting two trend lines. The file is tracking how investiments of two profiles: low and high risk. Now I want to plot a trend line, as in the below R base plot, but using gnuplot. My data file looks like:

```
date,investpercent,expenses,savings,low,high,objective
2015-09-25,5.0,1.0,2.0,1,2,2.0
2016-09-25,6.0,1.0,2.0,1,2,2.0
2017-09-26,6.0,1.0,2.0,2,4,2.0
2018-09-27,5.0,40.0,60.0,10,40,-49904.0
2018-09-27,5.0,40.0,60.0,20,50,-169960.0
```

[image: This is how I want it to look like]

```
set key autotitle columnhead
plot '~/Downloads/finances.csv' using 1:5
```

I am using autotitle because of the header in the first line, it removes an error, but obviously sets a title, which I don't need. It would be nice to know how to ignore the headers too.

My question is:

- How can I plot the trend using the values on columns 5 and 6 in y using dates as the x axis using gnuplot?

Comment: Have you tried a gunplot manual / tutorial / the gnuplot help? Your question seems very basic, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
set key autotitle columnhead
set key top left
set datafile separator ","
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'
set xdata time
plot 'test.txt' using 1:5 w l t 'low',  'test.txt' using 1:6 w l t 'high'
```

which yields:
[image]